# ¿Como puedo retornar el valor de una función anidada en otro lugar?

Tags: javascript, funciones

**Este es el código**

Lo que quiero es retornar el valor de la función C, en otro lugar fuera de la función A.

Según estouy usando un closure, pero no me ha salido bien.

```
function A(x) {
    
      function B(y) {
     
        function C(z) {
        
          var suma= x+y+z;
          return {
            obtenerValor: function()
            {
              return suma;
            }
          }
        }
       C(1);
      }
     B(2);
  }
var contenedor=A(1); 
console.log(contenedor.obtenerValor());
```

Comment: No estás devolviendo valor en A, ni en B. Intenta `return B(2);` en lugar de solo llamar a B y lo mismo cuando ejecutas C, agrega el `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Solo te falta agregar `return` en la llamadas a las funciones `B` y `C`

#### Demo:

```js
function A(x) {

  function B(y) {

    function C(z) {

      var suma = x + y + z;
      return {
        obtenerValor: function() {
          return suma;
        }
      }
    }
    return C(1); // ACA
  }
  return B(2); // ACA
}
var contenedor = A(1);
console.log(contenedor.obtenerValor());
```